# I need my Delphi IOS FMX application to continue running in the background

Tags: ios, delphi, notifications, apple-push-notifications, firemonkey

I have a Delphi FMX application for iOS where I need it to remain running in the background.
My application communicates with a server, and returns some strings that will be used for notification. And I need to query this server every 3 minutes and transform the return string into a local notification.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Dave Nottage made a demo project that does this: https://delphiworlds.com/2016/05/allowing-ios-app-run-background/

Comment: I analyzed this example but it didn't work for me. It may be related to the iOS version, and I need the app to run in the background continuously and not just for 3 minutes.

Comment: iOS has even stricter policies about background execution than Android, and what you describe is going to be impossible. Why does the device itself need to do the querying? You may be better off having that happen at the server, and send a push notification when it actually has to notify the device

Comment: Dave is correct. You can't write an iOS app that behaves this way in any language.  Apps that are suspended can't continue to execute and can't make/maintain network connections.  Perform the checks on your server and use push notifications.

Comment: Going through the Apple Push Notification service (APNs) so it handles the delivery of notifications to a users’ device is the proper way.